# How do I build an alpha emitter?

Tags: radiation, particle-physics, accelerator-physics

I would like to build an alpha emitter.  I suppose I had some vague idea of knocking the electrons off of some helium.  But upon further examination the idea does strike me as...naive?  My question is then, how do I go about building an alpha emitter, cheaply, and with household/hardware store items.  (Besides springing for a smoke detector.)

Comment: I removed your last note about links because link-only answers are never acceptable here. That being said, it's possible this question is off topic for this site altogether. We'll see what others in the community say.

Comment: It's an interesting question but I think it's more of an engineering question than physics so I think it's off-topic.

Comment: The component you are trying to build is called the "source" or "injector" or "first stage" of an accelerator. I don't imagine that they are incredibly hard to make if your performance requirements are loose, but they do require you to be able to draw a vacuum and to be able to work safely with moderately high to very high voltage circuits. This wouldn't be my suggestion for a first project. I'd vote on-topic in keeping with my answer to [Should “How do I solve this experimental problem?” questions be on-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/).

Comment: Seems on-topic to me. Historically, Becquerel used naturally occurring uranium, and then the reason the Curies were considered so great was that they purified radium, which was a much more intense alpha source. Only later did people figure out how to make accelerators that could accelerate an artificial beam of alphas to nuclear-physics energies, i.e., the MeV scale. Building such an accelerator (cyclotron or van de graaff) could conceivably be a garage project, but it would be an *extremely* ambitious garage project.

Comment: The idea of knocking electrons off He is not naive, and is in fact the mechanism used for ion sources as @dmckee noted above.  Simple sources include the colutron - not calutron - which uses a hot wire filament, and a simple rf source using rf excitation. From the resulting plasma, you apply an extraction voltage and He ions come out.  The electronics, vacuum system, and He gas bottle all are unlikely to be found in local stores.